# C - Free allocated memory on SIGINT

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, free

I want to write a program which will fill the computer's memory with 0's until `malloc()` fails. However, I wasn't sure if killing the program with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> would free this memory. I added some signal-handling code, so that when the program receives `SIGINT`, the allocated memory is freed and the program is killed.

My code appears to work, but I want to know if this method of freeing memory on `SIGINT` makes sense, or if there is a better way to do it.

My code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

int *ptr;

void inthandler(int dummy) { /* what does this argument do? */
   extern int *ptr;
   free(ptr);
   exit(-1);
}

int main(void) {
   signal(SIGINT, inthandler);
   extern int *ptr;
   while ((ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr)) != NULL) {
         *ptr = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: sigaction() will pass the signal number as your "dummy" argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I wasn't sure if killing the program with Ctrl+C would free this memory.

On any modern OS, it will.

> My code appears to work, but I want to know if this method of freeing memory on SIGINT makes sense, or if there is a better way to do it.

Your code is *deeply flawed* (in addition to being pointless).

`malloc` and `free` are not async-signal safe. Calling them from a signal handler invokes undefined behavior, and your program may crash at random times.

Finally, your `inthandler()` is never actually called -- you need to call `signal()` or `sigaction()` to actually set the `inthandler` as a `SIGINT` handler.

**Update:**

> I added the signal() call to the program.

Like I said, this made the program *worse* (because calling `free()` in a signal handler is unsafe).

> if killing the program frees its memory, why is it necessary to call free() on allocated memory after the program is done using it?

As Chris Dodd commented, it is never necessary to `free` memory in a program which is about to exit -- the OS will do that automatically.

It is only necessary to `free()` memory IFF the program will keep running *and* will allocate more memory in the future. In that case, if the program doesn't `free()` memory it has previously allocated, it will *eventually* run out of heap.

Comment: I added the signal() call to the program. Also, if killing the program frees its memory, why is it necessary to call free() on allocated memory after the program is done using it?

Comment: @spitemim: It is never necessary to call free() on allocated memory if the program is just going to exit.  You only need to call free() when memory is no longer needed AND the program is going to keep running.

Comment: Thank you for the information:). So it is only necessary to free() memory when it is no longer in use & the program will keep running, and never in a signal handler.

Comment: @spitemim That's correct. A word on etiquette: if the answer helped you, upvote it. If it answered your question completely, accept it.